# Definition of free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

I am trying to learn about free groups(as part of my Bachelor's thesis), and was assigned with Hungerford's Algebra book. Unfortunately, the book uses some aspects from category theory(which I have not learned). If someone has an access to the book and can help me, I would be grateful.

First, in theorem 9.1(2003 edition), he proves that the set of all reduced words, $F(X)$, of a given set $X$ is a group(under the operation defined), using "Van Der Waerden trick".
At some point in the proof he says:" since $1\mapsto x_{1}^{\delta_{1}}x_{2}^{\delta_{2}}\cdots  x_{n}^{\delta_{n}}$, under the map $|x_{1}^{\delta_{1}}|\cdots |x_{n}^{\delta_{n}}|$, then it follows that $\varphi$ is injective".  Can you please explain how did he get this conclusion?

Second, he found that this $\varphi$ is a bijection between a set and a group, and he concludes that since the group is associative then also the set is. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: I sympathize.  I just pulled the book off my shelf and read the section in question.  It is dense and much too formal for one's first exposure to this.  I wish I had a better reference for you.

Comment: @Randall, Thank you for sympathy. I am just afraid to let my supervisor down by saying that it a bit difficult for me to get it all done in a week.

Comment: Do you have any good intuition about what $F(X)$ **should be** as a group, in a down-to-earth sense?  If not, this is why you can't read it:  his exposition is not going to help you learn what it is, only to prove (really, really rigorously) that it does what you want it to do as a free object.  In some sense, free groups are the simplest groups conceptually, but getting the details right is hard (and not always worth it up front).

Comment: IMHO, this link is a better starting point than Hungerford:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667282/precise-definition-of-free-group?rq=1

Comment: I think that I have an idea about what $F(X)$ should be as a group, and I fully understood the construction of the set $F(X)$, and how the operation on the set works. In the theorem I have problem with, he is just trying to avoid the ugly proof(by induction) of the associative law on the group by finding a group in which induces its associative law on $F(x)$(hope I am not wrong).

Comment: Yes, he is (painfully) trying to prove that associativity holds in $F(X)$.  Note than even he declares his proof as a "sketch."