# Central Concept of Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory

Is it reductionist to say "Universal properties are the central concept of Category Theory". And if so, is it a useful fiction to keep in ones head as they are learning the subject?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63160/589

Comment: The nice thing about category theory is that it admits several central concepts, each of which can be reduced to the others: universal properties, adjoint functors, Kan extensions, etc.

Comment: Those definitions are all "equivalent"?

Comment: They're not equivalent, but they're interdefinable. Limits and colimits are special cases of Kan extensions, which are a special case of initial and terminal objects, which are a special case of adjoint functors, which are a type of Kan extension...

Comment: Okay, thank you.